# Simple JavaScript not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, html, browser, compatibility

I have some simple JavaScript in three divs:

```
<div class = "bbc">
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://output81.rssinclude.com/output
        type=js&amp;id=857232&amp;hash=8ea1a6373cb556ad71ecb072bed32932">
    </script>
</div>
<div class = "uefa">
    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://output33.rssinclude.com/output
        type=js&amp;id=859685&amp;hash=2142c0f49e8b94bc63f569ab271fabb0">
    </script>
</div>
<div class = "sky">
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://output39.rssinclude.com/output
        type=js&amp;id=859678&amp;hash=8b9f8b0ffa4c7cdf100d093ba0f0f630">
    </script>
</div>
```

It displays fine in Safari, but not in other browsers (tried Chrome & Firefox.

They are simply generated by rssinclude.com so I'm not sure what's stopping them from working.

What is the likely cause of the problem?

Many thanks,

Comment: its not working on safari also the link is not working

Comment: These 3 links give 404 Not Found errors.

Comment: I'm not sure why that is. They work fine for me, they're RSS feeds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try open the links and you'll see, that none of the url are valid.

The "`&amp;`" is an html code, which replaces an "&" char. After output there have to follow an "?" char for parameters. Try these url's:

```
<div class = "bbc">
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://output81.rssinclude.com/output?type=js&id=857232&hash=8ea1a6373cb556ad71ecb072bed32932">
    </script>
</div>
<div class = "uefa">
    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://output33.rssinclude.com/output?type=js&id=859685&hash=2142c0f49e8b94bc63f569ab271fabb0">
    </script>
</div>
<div class = "sky">
    <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://output39.rssinclude.com/output?type=js&id=859678&hash=8b9f8b0ffa4c7cdf100d093ba0f0f630">
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: I've made those changes, it's still working fine in Safari but hasn't changed anything for other browsers.

Comment: @MattCUK try turning off an AdBlocker or something you have on your client side.

Comment: @ReCaptcha - I've looked into that previously. My JavaScript is set always run on all sites in Chrome.

Comment: @c0d3b34n made those change, no change in other browsers.

Comment: @MattCUK have you checked you source code in browser? Can you post the relevant segment?

Comment: @c0d3b34n http://pastebin.com/A2sDRhwZ this is the body it's included in and doesn't work for the browsers mentioned. If that's what you'd like?

Comment: @MattCUK i've copypasted your code and ran it successfully at Firefox 28: http://prntscr.com/39vjlg